# Customizing ListBox WP7

Tags: xml, web-services, windows-phone-7, listbox

I want to display the data extracted before in a customized list, but the method i found to extract that data doesn't make things easy for me , so i would find a way to display my data without changing the xml reading method.
This is how i want my list to be(xml):

```
 <ListBox Height="516" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,74,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                        <Image Source="{Binding  wkpinImage}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
                        <StackPanel Width="370">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Low}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding High}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Condition}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="26" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And this is the xml reading method(c#):

```
  while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {
                    case ("day_of_week"):
                        {
                            listBox1.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
                              {
                                  Content = reader.GetAttribute("data")
                              });
                            Day = Content.ToString();
                        } break;
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using MVVM approach to bind items to your listbox.

Here is a very good tutorial of how to MVVM to bind items to a listbox:

http://www.labo-dotnet.com/post/Creating-your-first-MVVM-silverlight-application-on-windows-phone-7.aspx

There are lot's of good points about MVVM:

- Less coding
- Your binding can be optimized for huge datasources
- easier maintainance
- cleaner code
- ...

Comment: I wanted something easier , isn't there one?

Comment: In my point of view No :) Take it easy, it's very robust. just follow tutorials, there are also numerous videos on Channel9

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best solution AT ALL is XML serialization!

You should simply create a serializable class
(
REMEMEBER:
- use base data types (otherwise you'll need translation properties)
- only public properties can be serialized
- keep a constructor WITHOUT parameters
)

```
...
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class SerializableClass
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Day")]
    public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public CustomEnumerationType PublicPropertyNotToReadWrite
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

An than use these static methods to serialize (OUTPUT the object of your class TO SOMETHING [eg. XML file / stream]) and deserialize (INPUT FROM SOMETHING [eg. XML file / stream] TO a new instance of an object of your class):

(THE NEXT 2 STATIC METHODS CAN READ/WRITE A SERIALIZABLE OBJECT FROM/TO AN ISOLATEDSTORAGE FILE!!)

public static object DeserializeObject(string fileName, Type objectType)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            using (TextReader xmlReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);

```
            return xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }

    public static void SerializeObject(string fileName, object target, Type objectType)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = appStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (TextWriter xmlWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);

            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, target);
        }
    }
```

There's nothing better than this approach, in my opinion!

I hope this can help you!